# new command, tabular, new row without extra spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, overleaf, paragraphs

I'm currently creating my CV on overleaf using a template as I'm really unfamiliar with LaTeX. I see that there is a line to create a newcommand which creates a tabular section to input my experiences:

```
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[3]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2}, \skilllocstyle{#3} \\
}
```

This returns something like this:
[image]

I wanted to add a small blurb for descriptions, so I added to the code:

```
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[4]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2}, \skilllocstyle{#3} \\ & \skilldescstyle{#4}\\
}
```

which returns [image]

How can I remove the extra line between the description and the title? I understand it comes from the `\\` in the command, but because I need a new line to put the description in, I'm not sure how to avoid it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `\\[1pt]` or `\\[1ex]` to see if the gap closes

Comment: @JamesT unfortunately neither did. ```\\[1pt]``` remained the same and ```\\[1ex]``` actually increased the spacing a bit. Does this mean something else in my document is overriding this setting?

Comment: It is difficult to say, usually a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` is required to say for certain how to fix it. I am assuming based on the command that someone may be able to help as it is just presentation. You could always try `\\[-2ex]` or negative values in general but I am not sure it is sustainable and may mess up other things. Can you condense your code down a little and edit it into your question? I understand OverLeaf/OpenCV might make that difficult though.

Comment: If the gap increases with a positive adjustment, try a negative adjustment `[-1ex]`.  This is a hack, but if you'll be using it only once, ...

Comment: @JamesT you know what I think I figured it out - the template had an existing environment for lists that had a ```\vspace{}``` parameter. I used that along with your suggestion of ```-2ex``` and that did the trick. Hopefully it doesn't mess things up down the road - appreciate the help! If you want to copy the comment as an answer I'm happy to mark it solved!

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton - handy hack did do the trick :)

Comment: @IcyLemons I feel dirty posting that as an answer but it helps keep the site clean, glad to help best of luck with your CV!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decrease the gap when needing to use `\\`, it is sometimes suitable to add an adjustment after such as `\\[-2ex]`, negative lengths are suitable too but it may have other unintended effects.